# Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.53

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

When I try to run the command `mvn appengine:update` on my google appengine project the whole thing fails to build. Here is the error I get

```
`[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.53: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.53 (C:\Users\Rahul\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-maven-plugin\1.9.53\appengine-maven-plugin-1.9.53.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 19 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 28 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.696 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-08T17:06:12-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Rahul\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you declared `<pluginGroup>com.google.appengine</pluginGroup>` in your [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups)?